# How to simulate encoders in Gazebo 11?

Tags: gazebo, urdf, sensors, gazebo-plugin, ros-humble

I am using a differential drive robot and would need to have access to the encoder counts from the simulator, but I cannot find an encoder plugin anywhere. Since encoders are one of the most basic sensors in mobile robotics, I assume that there is already an existing solution to simulate them in  Gazebo.
To make it clear, I know that differentialDriveController outputs the odometry alreade, but I would need to go lower level and access the counts of the wheels.

Thank you in advance!

Setup:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- ROS2 Humble
- Gazebo classic 11
- Description file format: URDF.

Comment: You want to simulate A/B encoders for position or ticks for velocity only? However, I'm not aware of such a plugin.
Being curious: Why you want to simulate this at all? Isn't this the job of you hardware driver to calculate the joint states?

Comment: Thanks. I want to use the ticks for velocity estimation. The reason I'd like to go low level is that I want to make a material to explain (teach) some people how encoders work and how they are used to estimate speed.